# I have the following exercise but with the data I'm not able to get the answer.

Tags: geometry

In the picture if AC=8m and AC'=10m and the area of ABC=
$40m^2$ then the area of the triangle AB'C' is:

[image]

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Are there are right angles or parallel lines here?

Comment: How can I get pass of the only notion that I have which is: in the area formula I have two unknown terms. Or How can I get at least an angle to work with?

Comment: No, that's all the info that the excercise displayed.

Comment: Mistake. Sorry my bad.

Comment: I think that's not the only mistake, it should be AC=8m, not AB (that would be a geometric impossibility). And the seemingly parallel lines have to be parallel, it's not solvable otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit: Professor Vector for fixing the question.

Assumptions: line $BC$ and line $B'C'$ must be parallel. $ACC'$ and $ABB'$ are straight lines.

Edit to simplify explaination:

$$\frac{AC'}{AC}=\frac54=k$$

Since $\triangle ABC$ is similar to $\triangle AB'C'$.

$$\text{ Area of } \triangle AB'C' = k^2 \text{ Area of } \triangle ABC$$

Comment: Wha's k? Please.

Comment: defined in first line. I am using the concept of similarirty. the bigger triangle is an enlargement of the smaller triangle with scale $k$.

Comment: included the assumptions. Thanks.

Comment: These are the possible answers. I don't get how to obtain any of those with your answer. $72,5 m^2$
$256 m^2$
$62,5 m^2$
$160 m^2$

Comment: @Scoofjeer what are those numbers?

Comment: Sorry. Already edited.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60333/discussion-between-siong-thye-goh-and-scoofjeer).

Comment: 62, 5 is right when those CB C'B' parallel